# Implementar Runnable ou Estender Thread?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, thread, multithreading

Em diversos projetos Java, já vi estas duas formas de criar Threads:

Com `implements Runnable`:

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        //Código
    }
}
//Iniciada com uma chamada "new Thread(new MyRunnable()).start()"
```

Ou, com `extends Thread`:

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {
    public MyThread() {
        super("MyThread");
    }
    public void run() {
        //Código
    }
}
//Iniciada com uma chamada "new MyThread().start()"
```

- Qual o modo correto?
- Existe alguma vantagem ou limitação?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Segundo o Livro "Use a Cabeça! Java" você deve implementar Runnable, pois quando você estende Thread você está dizendo que sua Classe é um novo tipo de Thread, enquanto é apenas uma **Tarefa** de uma Thread.

Ao estender Thread sua classe receberá métodos (por herança) que provavelmente não fazem sentido para ela. Isso poderá até violar o ["Princípio da Substituição de Liskov"](https://robsoncastilho.com.br/2013/03/21/principios-solid-principio-de-substituicao-de-liskov-lsp/) e lhe trazer problemas já que sua Classe talvez não possa ser usada em todas as situações onde se usa um Thread.

Enfim, estenda Thread apenas se você precisar de um novo tipo de Thread, e isto fizer sentido na sua Aplicação. Caso contrário, implemente Runnable, até porque,
se você estender Thread não poderá estender mais nada, ficando limitado, mas, se você implementar Runnable você ainda poderá estender outra Classe.

Além disso, se você observar as Classes ["ThreadPoolExecutor"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html), ["ExecutorService"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html), etc. (que lhe permitem melhorar a performance com múltiplos Threads ao mesmo tempo que controlam a quantidade de Threads para que seu computador não trave) você verá que elas recebem **Tarefas**, ou seja, recebem Objetos Runnable ao invés de Threads; desta forma, se você implementar Runnable seu código poderá ser usado como uma Tarefa de um "Thread Pool" que gerencia as Threads para você.

Comment: Um ponto polêmico em implementar runnable é que você precisa seguir a assinatura do método run e não consegue lançar exceptions checadas, por exemplo.